# How can I choose the port to which I send the response

Tags: c++, boost-asio, modbus-tcp

I am currently trying to communicate with a PLC by using Modbus/TCP but even thought I can read the Modbus frame send by the PLC I must give the Modbus response to port 502 and the stream I use send to the port used by the PLC to send the frame. I tried using two stream to receive and send but when i close the first one the PLC get that as a timed out communication and then refuse the second connection.
If it can help you here is the code I use but for now it barely does anything else than allowing me to test the connection.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/config.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;


int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), 502);
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);

    while (1)
    {
        int i =0;
        string buff;
        char buf[30];
        tcp::iostream stream;
        tcp::iostream s("192.168.10.150", "502");
      acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf());
      getline(stream, buff);
          cout<<buff<<endl;
        s <<buff;
    }
}
```

If you have any suggestion.

Comment: "I must give an answer to port 502". TCP doesn't work this way. You need to carefully read the description of the protocol you have to implement, and implement it to the letter of the document. "Send the response to port 502" is too vague to be useful.

Comment: "TCP doesn't work this way" it's true, but my issue is with the Modbus/TCP protocole, if I had to use it in a standart PC to PC way it would be fine, but the PLC doesn't listen on the same port it used to send the Modbus frame, if I'm not mistaken both the server and client(master/slave) listen only to this port